# How to create a side bar like twitter for OSX ? Suggestions about development choices

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I'm curious to know how to create the sidebar used in twitter and many other Apps [image: Twitter App]

What i'm asking for is not about graphics, but i'd like to know which is the better way to create a structure to permit switching between different sections.

I don't like asking for help without start by an opinion, thus, this is mine:

1. Generic view structure would be created with a `NSSplitView`
2. I Need a `generic Model` class managing sections and taking a pointer to the current one.
   Here i'd add informations about image used for any section etc... (something like a custom UITabBarController for iOS.
3. The `Left view` of the `split View` would be connected to the `generic Model` and would be able to present its section and get the current one. Pushing a button will ask the `generic Model` to change the current section and load content in the `Right view` (some doubts about this use a Model that way :P probably not the better one)
4. The `Right view` loads other view controller as requested by `left View` **(i have may doubts  about how do that!)**

I'm on the right way ? how would you build a structure like that of Twitter ?

*(Off topic: I'd really appreciate correction of my terrible English to keep this question suitable for all users)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you need https://github.com/erndev/EDSidebar

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much how I would do it although what you call a "generic model" object, I would call a controller (because it fits in the controller part of MVC).

The right view would be a Tab View with the style set to "tabless" so you don't get the selection buttons at the top and the individual views within the tab view would be selected by the controller using `-selectTabViewItemWithIdentifier:`

That's how I would do it anyway.

Comment: Interesting! I never thought of using a tab view that way. 
Does a tab view load every views during  its "init" phase ? or is it possible to load them in a lazy way ?

Comment: @MatterGoal:  I'm not sure.  I imagine `viewDidLoad` will run at about the same time as the other parts of your window's `viewDidLoad`.  However, objects don't get drawn until they are visible.  For example, NSTableView will not send requests to its data source until the view it is on has been selected.